# Returning data from a queue of method calls

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, queue

I'm trying to create a queue to throttle and retry API calls to a service.

A shoddy diagram:

[image]

The queue needs to accept multiple types of calls (I think I've got this down), storing a queue of method calls and their parameters to the API library. If a call fails it needs to be retried at the top of the queue (Figured this out). It then needs to return data back to the method within the program that made the original call (Or a callback to another method), even if that call was delayed for a significant period of time due to the queue. All the while, not blocking the UI.

I've puzzled most of it out, except the part where I return data back to the original caller. Or at least to a method within that class that will accept the data (like a callback).

How would I go about doing this? How do I return data from the queue back to the rest of the program when the calls can be made from any number of classes? If I'm going to take advantage of callbacks, where/how do I store the callback information in the queue?

Another shoddy diagram of what the queue would do: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below will give you an idea.

```
// this is common practice for genertic classes like BaseApiRequest<T> -
// create parent class which does not have generic parameters
public abstract class BaseApiRequest : IDisposable {
    public abstract void Dispose();
    public abstract void SetException(Exception ex);
}

public abstract class BaseApiRequest<T> : BaseApiRequest {
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _signal;
    private Exception _exception;
    private T _result;

    protected BaseApiRequest() {
        _signal = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    }

    public T GetResult() {
        _signal.Wait();
        if (_exception != null)
            throw new Exception("Exception during request processing. See inner exception for details", _exception);
        return _result;
    }

    public T GetResult(CancellationToken token) {
        _signal.Wait(token);
        if (_exception != null)
            throw new Exception("Exception during request processing. See inner exception for details", _exception);
        return _result;
    }

    public bool TryGetResult(TimeSpan timeout, out T result) {
        result = default(T);
        if (_signal.Wait(timeout)) {
            if (_exception != null)
                throw new Exception("Exception during request processing. See inner exception for details", _exception);
            result = _result;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }        

    public void SetResult(T result) {
        _result = result;
        _signal.Set();
        var handler = ResultReady;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new ResultReadyEventArgs<T>(_result));
    }

    public override void SetException(Exception ex) {
        _exception = ex;
        _signal.Set();
        var handler = ResultReady;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new ResultReadyEventArgs<T>(_exception));
    }

    public override void Dispose() {
        _signal.Dispose();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ResultReadyEventArgs<T>> ResultReady;

    public class ResultReadyEventArgs<T> : EventArgs {
        public ResultReadyEventArgs(T result) {
            this.Result = result;
            this.Success = true;
        }

        public ResultReadyEventArgs(Exception ex)
        {
            this.Exception = ex;
            this.Success = false;
        }

        public bool Success { get; private set; }
        public T Result { get; private set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

That is possible base class for your api requests. When request is processed, SetResult is called by your processor. Caller creates request, publishes that to your queue and then have options:

1. Caller needs result synchronously. Then he calls GetResult which is a blocking call. If he does not want to wait forever in case something goes wrong, caller can use TryGetResult with timeout.
2. If result is not needed immediatly, caller can subscribe to ResultReady event, or just call GetResult some time later.

Now to handle your requests you have several options. One is adding handle logic right to BaseApiRequest. Then you extract BaseApiRequest from queue in your processor and just call Process on it. You might say that request should not contain logic to process itself, because it's, well, only request. Then consider a bit more complex class structure:

```
public interface IApiRequestHandler {
    // type of request which is handled by this handler
    Type RequestType { get; }
    void Validate(BaseApiRequest request);
    void Process(BaseApiRequest request);
}

// specific request
public class SomeDataRequest : BaseApiRequest<int> {
    public string Argument1 { get; set; }
    public long Argument2 { get; set; }
}

// specific request handler
public class SomeDataRequestHandler : IApiRequestHandler {
    public Type RequestType { get { return typeof(SomeDataRequest); } }

    public void Validate(BaseApiRequest baseRequest) {
        // safe to cast here
        var request = (SomeDataRequest) baseRequest;
        // validate and throw exception if something is wrong
        // no reason to validate when we already started processing
    }

    public void Process(BaseApiRequest baseRequest) {
        // safe to cast here
        var request = (SomeDataRequest) baseRequest;
        // do processing
        request.SetResult(1);
    }
}
```

Then, your api will look something like this:

```
    // this should be singleton
public class Api : IDisposable {
    private readonly BlockingCollection<BaseApiRequest> _requests = new BlockingCollection<BaseApiRequest>(new ConcurrentQueue<BaseApiRequest>());
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IApiRequestHandler> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, IApiRequestHandler>();

    public Api() {
        // find or explicitly register handlers in some way
        // here we just search them in current assembly
        foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(c => typeof (IApiRequestHandler).IsAssignableFrom(c))) {
            var handler = (IApiRequestHandler) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            if (_handlers.ContainsKey(handler.RequestType))
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Request handler for request type {0} already registered.", handler.RequestType));
            _handlers.Add(handler.RequestType, handler);
        }

        new Thread(ProcessingLoop) {IsBackground = true}.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessingLoop() {
        try {
            foreach (var request in _requests.GetConsumingEnumerable(_cts.Token)) {
                try {
                    // no casting from object or switches here
                    _handlers[request.GetType()].Process(request);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                   request. SetException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void StartProcessing(BaseApiRequest request) {
        if (_handlers.ContainsKey(request.GetType()))
            throw new Exception("No handlers registered for request type " + request.GetType());
        // validate synchronously
        _handlers[request.GetType()].Validate(request);
        _requests.Add(request);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was gone for a while., thank you for this response. So If I understand this correctly. I would create a `BaseAPIRequest`, pass that to my queue, it would process it in order and upon completion call `SetResult`. At this point, if I subscribed to the `ResultReady` event I would receive a callback when that fired with the results. Otherwise I would need to synchronously use `GetResult` or asynchronously poll `TryGetResult`. I would then dispose of the object by calling `Dispose`?

Comment: Right. TryGetResult is also to avoid deadlocks - pass relatively long timeout there and throw exception if you didnt get result after that timeout. Its generally safer. You may also add GetResult whcih accepts CancellationToken - pass that token to Wait method (use ManualResetEventSlim class in this case).

Comment: So after modifying that a bit, I've ran into what feels like a nasty code smell. Since each request takes different arguments (as an type of request in the API library) and returns different data (as a type of result).  I need to store them into the queue as an `object` rather than their respective types. I then need to cast them back to their respective types upon dequeuing so I can make the API call. This somehow feels wrong, since upcasting them is just an extraordinarily long switch statement covering all possible requests. In your opinion, is that an "ok" thing to do? If not, suggestions?

Comment: @douglasg14b consider my expanded and edited answer for more options about how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Alright, I think I've come to grips with how this will work. In this case I'm going to end up just having two classes per request, one for the request itself, and one for the results. Out of curiosity, what advantage does this present over a switch statement? (having a dozen classes vs having a switch statement with a dozen possibilities).

Comment: A related wrench, (you have no obligation to help me further) is that the API itself is built on a similar structure. There is a class for each type of request, and a class for each type of response. I created the reports section o f the API in this way. I wonder if rather than putting this into my program, I could just implement an optional queue in the API Library itself. So I'm not replicating all the request and result types.

Comment: Well I did not have obligations to help you in the first place :) So approach with separate IApiRequestHandler as in example above is more flexible, for example it allows external requests classes (created by third parties). All you need for that is scan some third party assembly for those IApiRequestHandler. You cannot do this with switch statement. That's just one example of why it's good. As for _optional_ queue in your api library itself - yes, why not. It only adds value to your api, not substracts anything.